# Can’t make query: select() and with()

Tags: query-builder, adonis.js

So here is my query

```
await Order
      .query()
      .with('order_status')
      .select('delivery_date')
      .fetch()
```

The result would be:

```
[{
   delivery_date: "2020-08-29"
   order_status: null
}]
```

as you can see the order_status is null, but when I removed the `.select` the order_status is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gave up using `.with`, just used `.leftJoin` got what I needed to do